# How can I change the index order of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, indexing

I have a button that has a function called clickNext(). Whenever that button is clicked, it increments the index position (scope.selected) on an array called 'arr1'.

```
<button type="button" class="right-btn col-xs-6" role="menuitem" ng-click="clickNext()">Next</button>
```

.

```
function clickNext()
        {
            scope.selected = (scope.selected + 1) % length;
        }


arr1 = [
        {apple: 1 , tango},
        {banana: 3, kappa},
        {orange:5, alpha},
        {apple: 8 , beta},
        {grape: 10 , sigma}
        ]
```

**Problem**

I have an identical array to arr1 called 'arr2'. What I'm trying to do is have the clickNext() increment to the next index position based on the *arr2 array* instead of the arr1 array.

Right now, the clickNext function still increments in the order of the arr1 array. For example, if I were to click the button, it would start on orange:5 then move to apple 8, etc.

```
arr2 = [
        {orange:5, alpha},
        {apple: 8 , beta},
        {banana: 3, kappa},
        {grape: 10 , sigma},
        {apple: 1 , tango}
        ]
```

**What I have tried**
    My though process to accomplish this is to use the findIndex() function and match the arr2 item to the arr1 item. That doesn't work, but maybe I'm structuring it wrong?

```
  clickNext(){
   var oldIndex = filteredToXs(scope.selected);
   scope.selected = oldIndex + 1;}

function filteredToXs( filteredIndex ) {
  var firstArr = scope.arr1[ filteredIndex ];
  var xsIndex = scope.arr2.findIndex( function(item) {
  return item.trackingNumber === firstArr.trackingNumber;
 } );
if( xsIndex >= 0 ) return xsIndex;
if( xsIndex === -1 ) return 0;  // Default value
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're not just using the second array directly. What is the desired benefit of trying to cross reference between them?

Comment: For simplicity sake in the example. It's mapped out in code, but the arrays have to be separate for referencing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. Please read my comments in the code sections as well.

I had to modify your source so I was able to create a fiddle for you.

HTML: I changed the click event and removed a css class that's not available

```
<button type="button" role="menuitem" onclick="clickNext();">Next</button>
```

Sampe Arrays:
They were containing invalid objects: I changed alpha, beta, tango, .. to a property. You can also define them as values.. this shouldn't matter:

```
var arr1 = [
    { apple: 1, tango: '' },
    { banana: 3, kappa: '' },
    { orange: 5, alpha: '' },
    { apple: 8, beta: '' },
    { grape: 10, sigma: '' }];

var arr2 = [
    { orange: 5, alpha: '' },
    { apple: 8, beta: '' },
    { banana: 3, kappa: '' },
    { grape: 10, sigma: '' },
    { apple: 1, tango: '' }];
```

Code:

```
var idx = 0;    //save current index of array 2

function clickNext() {
    idx++;

    //I'm comparing the array objects using a string compare- this only works because you said 'I have an identical array'
    //this may cause issues if you're objects are cross-referenced
    var find = function(array, obj) {   //lookup value from arr2 in arr1
        for (var i=0, l=array.length;i<l;i++)
            if (JSON.stringify(array[i]) == JSON.stringify(obj))    //adjust this line to your needs
                return array[i];
    }
    var result = find(arr1, arr2[idx])
    if (!result)
        throw new Error('not found- your arrays are not identical or you run out of index');
    console.log(result);
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k50y8pp5/